# second form is not getting validated django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

views.py

```
def crave_view(request):
    if (request.method=="POST"):

        form1=CraveDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        form2 = CraveReplyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print form1
        print form2

        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():

            crave_made = form1.save(commit=False)
            crave_made.person = request.user
            crave_made.save()  
            reply = form2.save(commit=False)
            reply.person=request.user
            reply.save()

            #login(request,crave_made.username,form1.clean_password2())
            messages.success(request, 'You Registered Successfully')

            #return HttpResponseRedirect('/details/')
        else:
            print form1
            print form2

            messages.error(request, 'Please enter all required fields')                     
    else:                    
        form2 = CraveReplyForm()
        form1=CraveDataForm()  


    return render(request, "crave/crave.html", { 'form1' : form1, 'form2' : form2 })
```

models.py

```
class crave_data(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post=models.TextField(blank = True,null = True)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post



class comments(models.Model):

    crave=models.ForeignKey(crave_data)
    reply=models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank = True,null = True)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.reply
```

forms.py

```
class CraveDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = crave_data
        exclude=['date', 'password1', 'password2', 'username', 'person']

class CraveReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = comments
        exclude=['date', 'crave', 'password1', 'password2', 'username']
```

my form1 is getting validated and getting saved in backend but form2 is not getting saved in backend. The error is in line "reply.person=request.user" the error is "crave_comments.crave_id may not be NULL"
please help me out i want to save the comment i.e reply for that perticuler crave_made i.e post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While saving and createing `reply`, you need to assign `crave` attribute as well.

Update your code to

```
        reply = form2.save(commit=False)
        reply.person=request.user
        reply.crave = crave_made
        reply.save()
```

Assuming you want to save with `crave_made` created just before.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working prperly,,,,,, Whats the problem over there exactly,,?,,,,,,,,,

Comment: @user3298313, while for `comments` object `crave` is required field and should not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using commit=True, when you save the form? The error you are getting is telling you that the reply needs to be saved before you can add a foreign key relationship.